# Java Regex match <li> not preceded by <br/>

Tags: java, regex

Title says it I guess, I want to match all `</li>` tags not proceeded `<br/>`, my try was this:

```
^(?!<br\/>$).*$<li>
```

but it won't work. 
Any tipps?

Comment: You might want to explain what you are wanting to do. This sounds like a job that needs to be working with the DOM, not the raw HTML source.

Comment: When you write “not preceeded”, you mean, “not _immediately_ preceeded”, or that there was no `<br/>` anywhere before the `<li>` ?

Comment: I mean immediately preceeded.

Comment: Then Rohit Jain's answer is suited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need that `.*$` in between. Specially that anchor is doing the danger. In fact you don't need anchors at all in the regex, unless you are testing for `<br />` at the beginning of the string.

And you are testing against `<li>` and not `</li>`.

Also `(?!...)` is for negative look-ahead. For look-behind, you should use: `(?<!...)`

Try using this regex:

```
"(?<!<br/>)</li>"   // You don't need to escape `/`
```

Note that, for more complicated cases of HTML parsing, you should [avoid using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1679863). Use an HTML parser instead. For Java, you can take a look at - [JSoup](http://jsoup.org)

Comment: Thank you, that regex works. I know Jsoup, but this is just for one special case im my Html code.

Comment: @Ascorbin. As far as just this case is concerned, it's ok to use regex.